# Haskell List of Data Type Filter Sub List

Tags: list, haskell, filter, sublist

I got a person data type that has a name and their weight looks like below.

```
data Person = Person
    {pName :: String,
     pWeight :: Double} deriving (Show)

persons :: [Person]
persons = [Person "Peter" 35.0,
            Person "Joe" 45.0,
            Person "Alex" 55.0,
            Person "Ruby" 60.0,
            Person "John" 65.0,
            Person "Ann" 35.0]
```

**Q1** If I want to filter and get the first sub set from the given persons list that their maximum weights sum is to be less than a given value how to do it?

eg Output if maximum Weight is 150.0

Person "Peter" 35.0

Person "Joe" 45.0

Person "Alex" 55.0

Total weight : 135.0

**Q2** If I want to get all the subsets of a maximum weight that is set

eg Output if max weight is 100.0

**Set 1**

Person "Peter" 35.0
Person "Joe" 45.0

Total weight : 80.0

**Set 2**

Person "Alex" 55.0

Total weight : 55.0

**Set 3**
...... so on

Comment: @jberryman well not exactly I am learning Haskell on my own. I did an python knapsack solution for my assignment totally on my own and trying to do the same with Haskell to learn it. I am just a beginner here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout well I saw other examples like using filter option but not sure how to use them that is why I raised a question like this

Answer (score 2):

The first can be done using a filter. The second seems like a knapsack problem. In which case you can search for strategies to solve it. If you run into any issues after you write your code, please re-post here and the community will be glad to help.